# How to understand the relationship of Nodejs, SPA and API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Recently I attended a presentation of SPA/API/Nodejs, it looks good, so I start to google a lot and try to figure out, but get confused more.

It seems that in a SPA website, when use click, for example, a user's profile, it will call some API like `http://example.com/profile/username` and get a JSON data and will be displayed.

And I found a lot of frameworks, express.js/meanjs/Mojitojs/angularjs/reactjs and so on. really get lost.

So I'm going to develop a website, which will not be a SPA, but I really like Nodejs, so  I'll use nodejs and i also like the idea of API to get data and display.

Can you recommend some framework to start?

Comment: express js is best for your choice. Use angular js on your front end.

Comment: there are pros and cons to every framework.  nobody else can tell you what is going to be the best for you, your team, or your project.  that evaluation relies upon too many factors to count, such as site size, user count, server choice, database needs, mobile access requirements, security needs, etc.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SPA Frameworks: [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), [React.js](https://facebook.github.io/react)
- Node.js Webserver frameworks: [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/), [Meteor](http://meteor.com), [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org)

You can also check [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/generators/) generators which help you to create a project skeleton.

Comment: Thank you, since I'm not going to do SPA website, so AngularJS and React.js is not my choice then.